# Sails JS, Query database without a Model

Tags: sails.js

I need to run query to the association table (created by sails), So I cannot use 
"Model.query",because I don't have model for this table.
And I couldn't find the solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: Why you don't create a model for your association table ? If you really need to make a request on it just create a model. I don't know if you can make a query without model.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @jaumard when the (mongodb) database is already there with data (from another app, not sails app) in it, and I want to use that database with a new sails.js app, can I just create a Model which has the same structure like the Collection in my database? and the data will not be deleted or modified at all? (!important!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any model defined, you have to use relevant adapter to do it. I have done it with `mysql`. As you have not said what database you are using, I can't help you to the point. But I can guide you. An example with `mysql` adapter is following.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : sails.config.connections.mysql.host,
    user     : sails.config.connections.mysql.user,
    password : sails.config.connections.mysql.password,
    database:  sails.config.connections.mysql.database
});
connection.query(queryString, function(err, records){
    // Do something
});
```

Or if you have a any model defined, then you can run any raw query with `Model.query(queryStrign, callback)`.

Comment: can I use default model methods to generate sql for some parts? I mean where(criteria) - Or do I need to parse it by myself?

Comment: @Crusader, can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to make sql from string + parsed criteria from request, something like this:
`'select ... from table join table 2' + Model.where(request) + Model.order(request) + Model.limit(request)`

Answer (score 3):

you can use other model object like `User.query(sql,function(err,result){});` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to the party but I did manage to find a way to query a connection without defining or using any models:

```
sails.adapters['sql-server'].query('my-sqlserver',null,'select *...', null, function(err, data){
  if(err)...
  return data;
});
```

I'll admit, it is a bit long but it works.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you got this? @karmic